# Angular tab - Cant place the two tabs buttons centered and 50% witdh

Tags: html, css, angular, button, tabs

This is my application that i am trying to build : [image: Aplication]

I am working on the blue tab, that is a Angular tab. My project is on Ionic, but i couldnt make the ionic tab to work, so i made a angular that i am more familirized with.

My goal is to make the two tab buttons with 50% witdh of the tab bar but i tried averything i cant make that.

My tab:

```
 <mat-tab-group color= "primary"  backgroundColor="primary" headerPosition="below">
        <mat-tab label="Oponent Damage" >
          <div *ngIf="this.pokemon1WasSelected && this.pokemon2WasSelected && this.leagueSelected && this.lifeCreated">
            <div *ngFor="let eachMove of this.leaguePokemon[this.pokemonNumber2].moves;let i=index">
              <ion-row>
                <ion-col><p>{{eachMove}}</p></ion-col>
                <ion-col size="3"><p> HP: {{this.pokemonHPShow[i]}}</p></ion-col>
                <ion-col><p> Move Damage: {{this.allMovesDamageArray[i]}}</p></ion-col>
              </ion-row>
              <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                  <ion-progress-bar  [value]="pokemonHPbyMoveArray[i]"></ion-progress-bar>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col  id="teste1" size="3">
                  <div>
                    <p [ngClass]="{'green-class': this.tankItAwnserArray[i] === 'YES!', 'orange-class': this.tankItAwnserArray[i] === 'Optional', 'red-class': this.tankItAwnserArray[i] === 'NO!' }"> {{this.tankItAwnserArray[i]}} </p>
                  </div>
                </ion-col>
              </ion-row>
            </div>
          </div>
        </mat-tab>
        <mat-tab label="Your Damage"> Content 2 </mat-tab>
      </mat-tab-group>
```

I have other problems, but for now i am trying to solve this one.
God i have css and this alight things xD

Comment: Hi Fábio, did my suggestion below help you to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Angular Material documentation, you could [center](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#label-alignment) the tabs with `mat-align-tabs="center"`.
In your case, since you want the tabs to have 50% width, you can simply stretch the tabs:

```
 <mat-tab-group mat-stretch-tabs color="primary" backgroundColor="primary" headerPosition="below">
  <mat-tab label="Oponent Damage" >...</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Your Damage">...</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```